# in mvc4 return html file from different directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Here is my code, actually i am trying to return a html file from other directory, and my code return the html page, but it doesn't return the Image of that page, can anyone suggest me how to do the same. Mean how to return the html page with image from different directory.

```
 public ActionResult GetHtml()
        {
            //var encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            //var htm = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerFilePath"].ToString()
+ "CPL\\" + "CPLPolicy\\" + "IMS.htm", encoding);
            //byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(htm);
            //Response.OutputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            //Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition { Inline = true, FileName = "index.htm" }.ToString());
            //return File(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerFilePath"].ToString() + "CPL\\" + "CPLPolicy\\" + "IMS.htm", "text/plain");
            //return File(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerFilePath"].ToString() + "CPL\\" + "CPLPolicy\\" + "IMS.htm", "text/html"); 
            var result = new FilePathResult(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerFilePath"].ToString()
+ "CPL\\" + "CPLPolicy\\" + "IMS.htm", "text/html");
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: So the HTML page is rendered, but without the image?  Your html page probably uses relative URLs for the image, which breaks when you render like this.

Comment: So What i should do ...to which it can render image as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it looks like your HTML pages use relative URLs like this:

```
<img src="testImage.jpg">
<img src="~/images/testImage.jpg">
```

The best thing to do is to update your HTML pages to absolute URLS like this:
    http://www.yoururl.com/images/testImage.jpg

If you can't modify your HTML pages, then you need [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  Then you can return the HTML like this in your controller:

```
string fileLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerFilePath"].ToString() + "CPL\\" + "CPLPolicy\\" + "IMS.htm";
string html = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
string websiteUrl = "http://www.yoursite.com";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

foreach (var img in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img"))
{
    img.Attributes["src"].Value = new Uri(new Uri(websiteUrl), img.Attributes["src"].Value).AbsoluteUri;
}

doc.Save(writer);

string content = writer.ToString();
return File(content, "text/html");
```